# Remove Class of the element using Angular2

Tags: angular

I have two elements. When one element is hovered another element's one class should be removed.

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
    selector:'display'
    template:`

     <div #myname />
     <p class="DN"> My name is Dude...</p>

    `

})
 export class DisplayComponent{
}
```

When `div` is hovered the class `DN` of `p` tag should be removed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could leverage the [`NgClass`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgClass-directive.html) directive and the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events:

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
    selector:'display'
    template:`

     <div (mouseenter)="showDNClass = false" (mouseleave)="showDNClass = true" #myname />
     <p [ngClass]="{ 'DN': showDNClass }"> My name is Dude...</p>

    `

})
export class DisplayComponent {
    private showDNClass: boolean = true;
}
```

---

> See [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zVAIum3t63u2HROwYF6C?p=preview) for example usage